# OleDbCommand with ORACLE query not updating table

Tags: c#, oracle, sql-update, commit, oledbconnection

I have tried everything, googled for days, but nothing I found helped me.

I have Oracle 9i db, table TIME_UNITS that have several fields - for my purposes I use only 3, defined as:
**CODE** - `VARCHAR2(6)`, **FOR_IN** - `VARCHAR2(1)`, **FOR_OUT** - `VARCHAR2(1)`. My code is:

```
string strConString = "provider=MSDAORA;DSN=myDSN;user id=myUser;password=myPassword";
string strQuery = "UPDATE TIME_UNITS SET FOR_IN='Y', FOR_OUT='Y' WHERE CODE='202003'";

using (OleDbConnection oleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(strConString ))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strQuery, oleDbConn))
{
    oleDbConn.Open();

    cmd.Transaction = oleDbConn.BeginTransaction(); 
    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Transaction.Commit();

    oleDbConn.Close();
}
```

ExecuteNonQuery returns one row, but when I look into db using sqldeveloper nothing is changed. The same statement works perfectly in sqldeveloper using the same credentials. I've tried with and without transaction begin-commit, but still no change in database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe SQL Developer has pending commits? Try restarting SQL Developer. Happened here for me several times, too.

Comment: No, sqldeveloper works fine, if I do it from sqldeveloper it changes fields FOR_IN and FOR_OUT into 'Y' no problem. But if I do it from code, no error, ExecuteNonQuery returns 1, but nothing is changed in db (refreshed, restarted developer, but still no change)

Comment: I wonder that you don't get any error, the connection string is wrong. It must be `Data Source=myDSN` instead of `DSN=myDSN`

Comment: Should not be, the very same connection string works perfectly  when I use SELECT. It's UPDATE that is somehow failing, not committing. And credentials are OK, got permission to write.